# Expert-guided tour of an offshore wind farm in or near the North Sea?

Tags: europe, tours, sea-travel, guides, north-sea

A few months ago, there were expert-guided tours available of one of the Danish offshore wind farms. Those have stopped now.

Where can I find an expert-guided tour now? Not just a boat that heads out from a nearby port and does a trip out and back with some half-educated guesses or readings of a brochure from the ship's crew, but a proper expert-guided tour, with information and Q&A with someone who knows and understands the development and construction process?

I'm based in Britain, and Ireland, Sweden, Norway, Denmark, Germany, Netherlands, Belgium, France are all close enough for me, and those are the main countries developing offshore wind farms anyway, so my geographic area is the North Sea or thereabouts.

Comment: There is also an App called Windfarmlocator that allow you to find the closest wind farm globally. It give you a lot of informations about windfarms specs and realtime and overall energy production!
You can find it [here](http://www.windfarmlocator.com/)

Answer (score 4):

There's [aerial tours](http://www.windforce2014.com/north-sea-wind-farm-tour-offshore-wind-energy-live/) being offered from Germany for WindForce 2014.  They're going to be run on Monday, June 16 and registration closes on May 30.  [More details are available here](http://www.windforce2014.com/uploads/pdf/WINDFORCE2014_Details_Northsea_Windfarm_Tour.pdf).  There doesn't seem to be any restrictions on the passengers that I can see, i.e. industry membership, other than the cost.